# session in jsp getting null value on getAttribute

Tags: jsp, session, session-variables

I have the addedit.jsp page

where I am inserting myinput in a textarea

```
your input
    <input id="thistextfield" type="text"  name="ruleField" size="20" >
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">

<a href="SaveName.jsp">to savename</a>
```

my session gets stored in this page

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.lang.String" %>

<%
    String ruleField = request.getParameter( "ruleField" );
    session.setAttribute( "theName", ruleField );


%>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="test2.jsp">Continue</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my text2 page.
where I am supposed to get back the session

```
Hello,<textarea > <%= session.getAttribute("theName")%>  </textarea>
```

but the problem is that I get a null value in my textarea.
And I am using IntelliJIdea 12 and the getParameter and getAttribute show up in red as cannot resolve method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out the HTML form tags in addedit.jsp. Therefore when you click on the link 'to savename' you are not sending the form data 'ruleField' as a parameter in the request, you are not sending any data, that is why it is null.

Make the following changes to the addedit.jsp:

```
<form method="GET" action="SaveName.jsp">
    <input id="thistextfield" type="text"  name="ruleField" size="20" >
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">
</form>
```

and remove the following HTML (this is superfluous):

```
<a href="SaveName.jsp">to savename</a>
```

I had thought that you might want to use a link to submit the form rather than a button. Here is alternative code that uses the link to submit the form.

```
<form method="GET" action="SaveName.jsp" id="form1">
    <input id="thistextfield" type="text"  name="ruleField" size="20" >
</form>

<div onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit()">to savename</div>
```

Comment: I havent displyed the form tags but I have written them.

<a href="javascript:$('#tempForm').submit()">savename.jsp</a> 

I used this instead of this. but it didnt work either

Comment: In the address bar of the browser do you see the query string attached to the URL, like so: `SaveName.jsp?ruleField=test`? **test** being the value entered in the text input.

Comment: Thanks alex, got the error, there was a nested form, which I had forgotten to remove.